# ASP.NET expose controls to other class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been battling this for some time and I need some guidance.

I'm coding in ASP.NET 4.0 WEBFORMS.

**Question is: How to expose a textbox, Label or any other control to another class.**

I have a webform (see below).

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

}
```

**This is then referenced and sent to another class.**

```
public class SearchInitializer
{
    private WebForm1 _webform1;

    public SearchInitializer(WebForm1 Webform1)
    {
        _webform1 = Webform1;
    }

    public void ChewSettings()
    {

        _webform1 //can't find any control in here?!
    }

}
```

First I thought of **creating a public property** which I thought I could access from the reference I sent to the new class.. But nooo!

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public string KeywordBox1 
    {
        get {return txt_keyword.Text;}
        set {txt_keyword.Text = value;}
    }

}
```

The I tried to **inherit the Webform into the other class**. Making the the property available but no luck there.

```
public class SearchInitializer : Webform1
{
    private WebForm1 _webform1;

    public SearchInitializer(WebForm1 Webform1)
    {
        _webform1 = Webform1;
    }

    public void ChewSettings()
    {

        _webform1 //can't find any control in here?!
    }

}
```

Okay an abstract class migth be of use here, inheriting everything. But I think I got that wrong to. I have events and static classes, so they can talk with the page. But I really would like not to use a static class as a container to save all the info in my controls.
So these are the examples I have tried and they all failed. So this is me basicly trying to expand what I know ;) Thanks for reading!!
Why have they failed and how should I do it?

EDIT AS REQUESTED!

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

     protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         SearchInitializer searchIni = new SearchInitializer(this);
     }

}
```

Comment: why do you wanna do this? i dont see any reason to do this...

Comment: Your property approach is about right, why the _But nooo!_ ?  But most likely is you call it at the wrong moment. Add more context.

Comment: show how you create and use `SearchInitializer`

Comment: Intellisense does not show up the property at all? When I write _webform1. I cant access the property..?! Should I try findcontrol and do it that way? kinda defeats having made a public property.. ?!

Comment: @Igor done read the latest in my question

Comment: @CarlPalsson - how and where do you call `searchIni.ChewSettings();`?

Comment: @Igor from inside the class "SearchInitializer". Last thing I do in my constructor is to call ChewSettings(), to fetch all the data from the controls on the page.

Comment: The `KeywordBox1` approach looks like it should work. I'm confused as to why you wouldn't be able to access a public property on an object you are passing if you have done it all right...

Comment: Seconding Henk, how or why does your `public property` approach fail?

Comment: Also are you just assuming that if the intellisense doesn't work then it won't compile? Because sometimes intellisense just doesn't work. In this case try to write the code and compile it and see what the compiler has to say on the issue...

Comment: @Chris I know, But I have been Building N rebuidling my solution like a Pharaoh on crack getting his pyramids ready for his death... I don't assume ;)

Comment: @CarlPalsson - then your original approach must work. I suggest you create a small test project with a form with text box and SearchInitializer class and see that it works, after that figure out what is different in your current project.

Comment: I will thanks for all the help! And I will credit the you with upvotes and of course mark the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expose the controls there are two methods I can think of that you can employ.

You can remove the following statement from the `myPage.designer.cs` file and place it in your code behind as a public declaration:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox myTextBox;
```

becomes

```
public System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox myTextBox;
```

This should make it immediately accessible. My preferred method is to add a property for each specific control that you want to provide access to.

```
public System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox MyTextBoxElement
{
    get
    {
        return myTextBox;
    }
}
```

This allows to provide supplementary access controls if you need them or other conditionals. In any case, to access either the field or the property, the consuming object must reference this by your specific page type.

Comment: Can you explain "In your sample the following code fails because `this` is of type `System.Web.UI.Page` not of type `WebForm1`." Surely this is always of the type of the current object, ie `Webform1`...

Comment: @Chris: Nope. Sure can't. I can give you a few excuses as to why my brain would have thought that, but nothing reasonable :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but to access a `base` class within an inherited calss you need to use the `base` keyword, not declare an instance there of.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public string KeywordBox1
    {
        get { return txt_keyword.Text; }
        set { txt_keyword.Text = value; }
    }
}

public class SearchInitializer : WebForm1
{
    public SearchInitializer()
    {
    }

    public void ChewSettings()
    {
        // Works
        base.KeywordBox1 = "Red";
    }
}
```

If intellisense is not showing the property, try rebuilding the solution.  It will then refresh the list of available properties and it should show.

Comment: I tried property is still not shown in Intellisense. But thanks.. ;)

Comment: @CarlPalsson see Updated.  The properties of the base class are always available to the children, if they are public.  You intellisense might not be rebuilding as expected.  Try rebuilding the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your original approach must work. I suggest you create a small test project with a form with text box and `SearchInitializer` class and see that it works, after that figure out what is different in your current project.